# Is there a rioxarray version of xarray pad

Tags: python-3, rioxarray, xarray

I have a geocoded raster that I'd like to pad with NaNs to 64 x 64 pixels. I've tested `rioxarray.DataArray.pad_box()`, which does work, but it's a bit complex to calculate new bounding box corners that will give said shape.

Is there a way to simply pad the raster to my desired output shape? Like xarray's `DataArray.pad()`, but that computes the new spatial coordinates as well, which xarray doesn't do.

Example of xarray's pad:

```
import xarray as xa
import rioxarray as rioxa

im_xa = xa.DataArray(np.random.randint(0, 255, (37, 33), dtype="uint8"), 
          dims=('y', 'x'), coords={'x': np.linspace(447560, 447960, 33), 
            'y': np.linspace(6760930, 6761380, 37)})
im_xa = im_xa.rio.write_crs(3006)
xleft = np.ceil((64 - im_xa.shape[1]) / 2).astype('int')
xright = np.floor((64 - im_xa.shape[1]) / 2).astype('int')
yleft = np.ceil((64 - im_xa.shape[0]) / 2).astype('int')
yright = np.floor((64 - im_xa.shape[0]) / 2).astype('int')
im_xa_pad = im_xa.pad({'x': (xleft, xright), 'y': (yleft, yright)})
```

Windows 10, Python 3.8.2, xarray 0.15.1, rioxarray 0.1.1

Comment: Please clarify what software you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't currently a function like that in rioxarray.